# Building LINQ to Entities Expression tree with DateTime filter

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am trying to complete implementation of dynamic querying provided by Todd Sprang, please see this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express).
Currently I am trying to enable filtering by DateTime type, and I am struggling to make lambda expression using "greater than" and "less than" operators, so my SQL would appear like "WHERE someDate<='2017-04-27 00:00:00' AND someDate<='2017-04-27 23:59:59'.

I managed to extract an operator methods:

```
private static readonly MethodInfo DateTimeGreaterThanOrEqualMethod = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("op_GreaterThanOrEqual",
                                BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
private static readonly MethodInfo DateTimeLessThanOrEqualMethod = typeof(DateTime).GetMethod("op_LessThanOrEqual",
                        BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

And here is my DateTime lambda filter method:

```
    private static Expression<Func<TDbType, bool>> ApplyDateTimeCriterion<TDbType,
            TSearchCriteria>(TSearchCriteria searchCriteria, PropertyInfo searchCriterionPropertyInfo,
            Type dbType, MemberInfo dbFieldMemberInfo, Expression<Func<TDbType, bool>> predicate)
{
    var searchDateTime = searchCriterionPropertyInfo.GetValue(searchCriteria) as DateTime?;
    if (searchDateTime == null)
    {
        return predicate;
    }
    var valueDateMin = ((DateTime)searchDateTime).Date;
    var valueDateMax = new DateTime(valueDateMin.Year, valueDateMin.Month, valueDateMin.Day, 23, 59, 59);

    var dbTypeParameter = Expression.Parameter(dbType, @"x");
    var dbFieldMember = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(dbTypeParameter, dbFieldMemberInfo);
    var criterionConstantMin = new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(valueDateMin) };
    var criterionConstantMax = new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(valueDateMax) };
    //having problem down here, when trying to call static method which needs two parameters
    var greaterThanCall = Expression.Call(dbFieldMember, DateTimeGreaterThanOrEqualMethod, criterionConstantMin);
    var lambdaGreaterThan = Expression.Lambda(greaterThanCall, dbTypeParameter) as Expression<Func<TDbType, bool>>;

    var lessThanCall = Expression.Call(dbFieldMember, DateTimeLessThanOrEqualMethod, criterionConstantMax);
    var lambdaLessThan = Expression.Lambda(greaterThanCall, dbTypeParameter) as Expression<Func<TDbType, bool>>;

    return predicate.And(lambdaGreaterThan).And(lambdaLessThan);
}
```

I am having problem on calling Expression.Call because op_GreaterThanOrEqual is a static method with 2 parameters. Maybe I should not call op_GreaterThanOrEqual, maybe this has to be done in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am having problem on calling Expression.Call because op_GreaterThanOrEqual is a static method with 2 parameters

`Expression.Call` has several overloads, you need to use the proper overload for static methods (currently you are using the one with `instance` argument, hence for instance method).

Also don't create unnecessary `Expression[]` (the methods that receive multiple expressions usually use `params Expression[]`, so it will be created for you when needed):

```
var criterionConstantMin = Expression.Constant(valueDateMin);
var criterionConstantMax = Expression.Constant(valueDateMax);
```

And here are the calls in question

```
var greaterThanCall = Expression.Call(DateTimeGreaterThanOrEqualMethod, dbFieldMember, criterionConstantMin);
var lessThanCall = Expression.Call(DateTimeLessThanOrEqualMethod, dbFieldMember, criterionConstantMax);
```

> maybe this has to be done in another way?

There are specific `Expression` method like [GreaterThan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356438(v=vs.110).aspx) etc. corresponding to each C# comparison operator, so you don't bother getting operator method infos etc. and simply use:

```
var greaterThanCall = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(dbFieldMember, criterionConstantMin);
var lessThanCall = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(dbFieldMember, criterionConstantMax);
```

**Update:** In order to support `DateTime?` members, use the following:

```
var criterionConstantMin = Expression.Constant(valueDateMin, dbFieldMember.Type);
var criterionConstantMax = Expression.Constant(valueDateMax, dbFieldMember.Type);
```

and then

```
var greaterThanCall = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(dbFieldMember, criterionConstantMin);
var lessThanCall = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(dbFieldMember, criterionConstantMax);
```

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, but I am having trouble with nullable types: the field type is nullable (DateTime?) and I get Exception "The binary operator GreaterThanOrEqual is not defined for the types 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]' and 'System.DateTime'.", when calling Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual, as described above.

Comment: OK, I got this too:
var convertedFieldMember = Expression.Convert(dbFieldMember, typeof(DateTime));
var greaterThanCall = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(converted, criterionConstantMin);
var lessThanCall = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(converted, criterionConstantMax);

Comment: I would suggest different approach - see the update.