# GreaterThanOrEqual operator between lambda and constant

Tags: c#, expression

My question is how can I build lambda `c=> c.docdate >= DateTime.Today` by Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual  method.

Thanks

ps:

The purpose I do such things is I think I can apply such way to any query condition, such as int, decimal, . Then I can write any query condition by generic method and bind them together in any way.

for example:

I have a class like below:

```
public class DataRangeT<T> : IRangeValue<T>
    where T : struct
{
    Nullable<T> _high;
    Nullable<T> _low;
    public Nullable<T> High { get { return _high; } set { _high = value; } }
    public Nullable<T> Low { get { return _low; } set { _low = value; } }
}
```

Beacuse the High and Low is Nullable, so I should build my query like below

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> RangeCompare<T>(Expression<Func<T, K>> selector, IRangeValue<K> patten)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = f=>true;
        if (patten.High.HasValue)
        {
            predicate = predicate.And<T>(/* LowThanOrEqual */);
        }
        if (patten.Low.HasValue)
        {
            predicate = predicate.And<T>(/* GreaterThanOrEqual */);
        }

        return predicate;
    }
```

Because >= operator is not support in Nullable, then I think I should use GreaterThanOrEqual.

The method `predicate.And<T>()` is a help method I write to combine query dynamically.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you post more code and more description to the question?

Comment: What's the problem of using `>=`? It seems to be working fine in [this example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/U2XKgu)

Comment: Possibly [Expression.GreaterThan fails if one operand is nullable type, other is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2088231) or [Building LINQ to Entities Expression tree with DateTime filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43649673) apply.

Comment: See IComparable, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable

Comment: This is beginning to sound like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the purpose of what you're trying to do?

Comment: OK, your question seems clearer now.  But perhaps the answer to [Expression.GreaterThan fails if one operand is nullable type, other is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2088231) answers this also?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expression.GreaterThan fails if one operand is nullable type, other is non-nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088231/expression-greaterthan-fails-if-one-operand-is-nullable-type-other-is-non-nulla)